# Split strings in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am using nodejs and I get an array using walksync i.e.

```
var paths = ['Essential Classes.jade' , 'introduction.jade']
```

These are filenames inside a folder. Now i want only filename but not extension, So I have to split every string in array. But don't know how.I want the result like below

```
['Essential Classes' , 'introduction']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```js
var paths = ['Essential Classes.jade' , 'introduction.jade'];

paths = paths.map(e => e.replace(/\.\w+$/, ''));

console.log(paths);
```

Comment: Thanks guys. You are awsome

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to split each string in the array and get the first string, which is the file name:

1- Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var paths = ['Essential Classes.jade' , 'introduction.jade'],

paths = paths.map((str) => str.split('.')[0]);
console.log(paths);
```

2- Using a [normal function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions):

```js
var paths = ['Essential Classes.jade' , 'introduction.jade'],

paths = paths.map(function(str) { return str.split('.')[0] });
console.log(paths);
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :).

Comment: can you tell me about =>

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAsad `(arguments) => expression` is an arrow function, which is similar to `function(arguments) { expression }`.

Comment: Wow. Now its short. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me any source, where i can remain every time to ask question, because now i have again an error and again going to post.. that's problem.. Due to some privacy of stack

Comment: You can try forums such as Quora and education websites forums.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155156/discussion-between-syed-muhammad-asad-and-mr-geek).

Answer (score 0):

1. use . each to iterate the array
2. use split() to split the array value then get first index

```js
var paths = ['Essential Classes.jade', 'introduction.jade'];

var arr = [];


$.each(paths, function(i,v) {

  arr.push(v.split(".")[0])

})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```